# Running a command as soon as I save a file

Tags: xubuntu, execute-command

I want to run a command as soon as I save a specific text file. I know how to do it when the **file closes**, but I am looking for the code to execute as soon as I hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: What editor do you use?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using tools from the inotify-tools package, available in the archives or using other libraries such as pyinotify.

Comment: Would you elaborate?